# C# asmx WebService cast issue

Tags: c#, web-services, class, asmx

I have a C# asmx webservice `WP.asmx`, a string method `Authorisation(string PMSRequest)

```
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
[WebMethod]
public string Authorisation(string PMSRequest)
```

which Deserialises a JSON string to a a class called Details

```
class Details
    {
        public string Number { get; set; }
    }
```

here:

```
Details obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Details>(PMSRequest)
```

and eventually retrurns a string.

I am trying to call it from a browser

```
https://example.net/WP.asmx/Authorisation?PMSRequest="{\"Number\":\"5413\"}"
```

strong text
but I get an error

```
Could not cast or convert from System.String to My.Web.MyService.WP+Details

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value 
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.EnsureTypeAssignable(Object value, Type initialType, Type targetType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.ConvertOrCast(Object initialValue, CultureInfo culture, Type targetType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType(JsonReader reader, Object value, CultureInfo culture, JsonContract contract, Type targetType)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType(JsonReader reader, Object value, CultureInfo culture, JsonContract contract, Type targetType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
```

It works fine when I have the same code it in a C# Windows Form test app

Comment: You are calling a *SOAP* service. SOAP works with POST and XML, not GET and JSON. It has a schema from which clients can generate strongly-typed proxies. That's what happens when you add a `Service Reference`.  Even if you try to send data as JSON, it's still wrapped in XML. You get no benefit but lose all type checks, automatic serialization, standard support etc

Comment: Did you add `[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]` perhaps? That was meant for the original AJAX calls, where `X` means XML, specifically XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Thanx Pano. I did add it (see edited code) but I get the same result :(